# Replace values in dataframe with another dataframes values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with the same columns names and rows number but the elements' values are different. I need to change the value of each element in the first dataframe to 1 if its value in the the other dataframe is 1. I am stuck on this task. Any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it for your case is something like this:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                         

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], columns=["A"])                                                              

In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([9] * len(df1), columns=["A"])                                                                           

In [4]: df1                                                                                                                         
Out[4]: 
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  1
8  2

In [5]: df2                                                                                                                         
Out[5]: 
   A
0  9
1  9
2  9
3  9
4  9
5  9
6  9
7  9
8  9
```

Wherever the row of column `A` in `df1` is equal to `1`, insert `1` into the same row of column A in `df2`

```py
In [6]: df2.A[df1.A == 1] = 1                                                                                                       

In [7]: df2                                                                                                                         
Out[7]: 
   A
0  9
1  1
2  9
3  9
4  1
5  9
6  9
7  1
8  9
```

---

You could also use the [pd.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method, to replace the part `df1.A == 1`.

There are also many other ways to get the same thing done, but my example is the most straighforward :)